# Functional way of doing a loop of operations on an array

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I currently have a Java program which does something like the following:

```
  int nvars = 10;
  long vars[] = new long[nvars];
  for(int i = 0; i < nvars; i++) {
      vars[i] = someFunction(i);
      anotherFunction(vars[i]);
  }
```

I am converting it into Scala code and have:

```
val nvars: Int = 10
val vars: Array[Long] = new Array[Long](nvars)

for ( i <- 0 to nvars-1 )
    vars(i) = someFunction(i)
    anotherFunction(vars(i))
}
```

Any advice on how to make this (more) functional?

Comment: In a mathematical sense, functions have no side-effects, so you could make your "fuctions" side-effect free, returning a new array (or an immutable list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of useful constructor methods in the Array companion object, for example, for your situation here, you can use `tabulate`:

```
val nvars: Int = 10
val vars = Array.tabulate(nvars){ someFunction } // calls someFunction on the values 0 to nvars-1, and uses this to construct the array
vars foreach (anotherFunction) // calls anotherFunction on each entry in the array
```

If `anotherFunction` returns a result rather than just being a "side-effect" function, you can instead capture this with a call to `map`:

```
val vars2 = vars map (anotherFunction) // vars2 is a new array with the results computed from applying anotherFunction to each element of vars, which is left unchanged.
```

Comment: A question: isn't what you are proposing equivalent to two consecutive loops? I mean, in terms of the computational efficiency, how optimal is it?

Comment: @Daniel In regards to complexity, 2 loops are as complex as 1, or as 10. It's still linear (O(n)).

Comment: @Daniel It wasn't clear from your question whether you needed separate results from each function, or just the outcome of the second function. If the latter, then you could have compounded the functions together. Eg. if `anotherFunction` generates values (is not just side-effecting) you could write `Array.tabulate(nvars){ someFunction _ then anotherFunction _ }` (as suggested by someone in a proposed edit to my answer - sorry I can't see who that was now to give them credit).

Answer (score 4):

Use `map`. A call to map on an `Array` will return a new collection. So call `map` twice for each function you want to apply to all elements of the `Array`.

Some simple functions for demonstration:

```
scala> def addOne(l: Long) = l + 1
addOne: (l: Long)Long

scala> def addTwo(l: Long) = l + 2
addTwo: (l: Long)L
```

`map` the array `vars` using the functions defined.

```
scala> val vars = Array[Long](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
vars: Array[Long] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> vars.map(addOne(_))
res0: Array[Long] = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

scala> vars.map(addOne(_)).map(addTwo(_))
res1: Array[Long] = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Another approach that is "more functional" and probably a good exercise is to use a recursive function that takes a function as a parameter and applies the function passed in to each element of the `List`.

```
scala> def fun[A](as: List[A], f: A => A): List[A] = as match {
     | case List() => List()
     | case h::t => f(h) :: fun(t, f)
     | }
fun: [A](as: List[A], f: A => A)List[A]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider iterating over a range of `Long` values,

```
val vars = (1L to 10L).map(someFunction).map(anotherFunction)
```

This applies `someFunction` onto each value from the range, and then each intermediate result from the first `map` onto `anotherFunction`. Assumed it is that each function takes and delivers a values of type `Long`.

For converting `vars` onto a desired collection such as `Array` or `List` consider,

```
vars.toArray
vars.toList
```

Use `view` to apply both functions at once onto each value in the range, hence not having to create an intermediate collection from mapping `someFunction`,

```
(1L to 10L).view.map(someFunction).map(anotherFunction)
```